# Laravel using eager loading with union queries

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am using union to join 2 queries. On my first query i am using the `with` eloquent method to eager load its relationship, then on my second query i am usign join to combine the 2. I have tried many different ways but none have worked so far.

All the following attempts work if i just query `$establishments`.
All the relationships work correctly if i do an independent query.

Attempt 1

I simply added the `with` method. On my results, it doesn't show any results, it completely ignores it.

```
$establishemnts = Establishment::select('establishments.name', 'establishments.category_id',
        DB::raw("MATCH (establishments.name) AGAINST ('{$text}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as scores"),
        DB::raw("'establishment' as object_type")
    )
    ->with('category')
    ->whereRaw("MATCH (establishments.name) AGAINST ('{$text}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
    ->where('status_id', Status::ACTIVE);

$query = Event::select('events.name', DB::raw('null as category_id'),
        DB::raw("MATCH (events.name) AGAINST ('{$text}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as scores"),
        DB::raw("'event' as object_type")
    )
    ->whereRaw("MATCH (events.name) AGAINST ('{$text}*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
    ->where('status_id', Status::ACTIVE)
    ->union($establishemnts)
    ->orderBy('scores', 'desc')
    ->limit(6)
    ->get();
```

Result

```
{
    "data": [
    {
        "name": "Group",
        "category_id": null,
        "scores": 6.3736681938171,
        "object_type": "event"
    },
 ...
```

Attempt 2

Same query as Attempt 1, but added
`->union($establishemnts->getQuery())`
which i saw on some other responses. It also return the same results of Attemp 1.

Attempt 3

I thought since the first query was returning 5 results and the second returned 4, it was a mismatch and the reason for not event showing the column. So i added `DB::raw('null as category_id')` as another column so they both have the same amount. That didn't work either. It tells me they have different amount of columns.

Attempt 4

I added a `->with('promotions')` to the second query, so they would have the same structure.

Results 4

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "name": "Group",
        "category_id": null,
        "scores": 6.3736681938171,
        "object_type": "event",
        "promotions": []
    },
....
```

For all the results it gave me an empty `promotions` which is right because the `promotions` is empty. But it doesn't show the relationship for the first query. It's like `->with('promotions')` overwrote it.

Final Attempt

I switched the queries around. Query 1 became query 2 and did the join on the second query. This brought me the right relationship but got me thinking what happens when i want to eager load for both queries? Seems like the second eager loader always replaces or the first query with the eager loader never gets executed.

Comment: Do you have the relationship set up in the model?

Comment: @kerrin yes, all the relationships are correct, like i mention on top, they bring me the right data if i do the queries independent

Comment: Have the same issue,  Did you find a way for this ?

Answer (score -1):

Presuming an establishment can have many events, and an event can be held at more than one establishment, each model will need to be set up as having a many-to-many relationship.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Establishment extends Model
{
    /**
     * The events that belong to the establishment.
     */
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event');
    }
}
```

and the inverse:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model
{
    /**
     * The establishments that belong to the event.
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Establishment');
    }
}
```

Once the relationships are defined, you can eager load with the `with` method:

```
$establishments = Establishment::with('events')->get();
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but my questions was oriented more on using the `union` method on 2 queries while using eager loading on each one of the queries

Comment: its a search method, where i am searching 2 different tables, so instead of searching one table and then the other, with union i can use one query

Comment: What are the relationships? You have many-to-many establishments/events - how do the promotions and scores fit in?